# ks.test statistics between group of columns by row-wise in datatable r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.table and wish to do ks.test by grouping columns and compute p.value row-wise

```
df <- read.table(file.tsv, setp="\t", header=TRUE)
```

output looks like:

```
sno A B C D E
r1 1 3 5 6 7
r2 8 9 1 5 3
r3 2 4 6 8 10
r4 11 2 3 7 6
```

I wish to perform ks.stat grouping A,B vs C,D,E for each row

```
stats = ks.test(df[1,A:B],df[1,C:E])
```

And write the results to the df

```
df %>% mutate(pval = stats$p.val, hyp=stats$alternative)
```

So, that my final table is

```
sno A B C D E pval hyp
r1 1 3 5 6 7 0.005 two-sided
r2 8 9 1 5 3 0.42 one-sided
r3 2 4 6 8 10 0.003 two-sided
r4 11 2 3 7 6 0.0001 two-sided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(stats = list(ks.test(c_across(A:B),c_across(C:E))), 
         pval = stats$p.val, hyp=stats$alternative) %>%
  ungroup

#   sno       A     B     C     D     E stats    pval hyp      
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <list>  <dbl> <chr>    
#1 r1        1     3     5     6     7 <htest>   0.2 two-sided
#2 r2        8     9     1     5     3 <htest>   0.2 two-sided
#3 r3        2     4     6     8    10 <htest>   0.2 two-sided
#4 r4       11     2     3     7     6 <htest>   0.9 two-sided
```

Comment: Great solution. But the problem arises, when I want to write the output through write.table. Error in write.table(df, file = "df.ks.test.tsv", quote = FALSE,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'. Because, mutate also writes stats in the row.

Comment: Yes, you'll not be able to write a list column. You can remove the `stats` column with `select(-stats)` and try to write the output.